# How to find the value current row value if current row value match with previous row value in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to find the current row value if the condition matches with the previous row value

[image]

My condition is

1) if my trac column value is T645 then I have to check next transaction value is ‘T644’ or ’TA63’ or ‘T643’ any one of them in new column but not BZ12. I have to take TotalPremium value of T645 column other views not

My code is

```
sub Value = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[TotalPremium]),FILTER(ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[trac] = "T645" && EARLIER('Table'[trac])= "T644" || 
        EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) = "TA63" || EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) = "T643" && 
        EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) <> "BZ12" && 'Table'[Stat] = "PS"))
```

Output:

[image]

but Expected Output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved using index concept, I mean I have created the index column for comparing the current value and next value

**Code:**

```
New Val = 
    VAR device = 'Table'[trac]    
    VAR ind = 'Table'[Index]
    VAR preInd= ind-1
    VAR TotalPremiumPreDate  = 
      SUMX(
        FILTER(
          'Table', 'Table'[Index] = preInd && ('Table'[date] >= MIN('Table'[date]) 
          && 'Table'[date] <= MAX('Table'[date]) ) &&
          'Table'[trac] = "T645" && (EARLIER('Table'[trac])= "T644" || 
                EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) = "TA63" || EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) = "T643") && 
                EARLIER ('Table'[trac]) <> "BZ12" && 'Table'[Stat] = "PS"  
        ),
        'Table'[TotalPremium]
    )
    RETURN TotalPremiumPreDate
```

**Output:**

[image]